# Are there any configurable settings for "create a branch from a work item?"

Tags: azure-devops

Azure DevOps has a few handy integrated development tools from a task/story/work-item:
[image]

However when I use 'create a branch' this on my work system, every new branch defaults to branching from master, and it doesn't suggest a branch name.

In an ideal world I could set the default source branch to  and the branch-name would be //features/_. Are there any options in DevOps to do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, there are.**

But if you want a feature that only affect the default branch in this place, **then the answer is NO.**

[image]

But notice this will also change many other features, I suggest you don't change the default branch, just search the branches when create:

[image]

Comment: that is a useful feature though, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Mr.Boy Hi, may I know whether my answer answer your question? :)